# How to make iPhone App limit use to one per day

Tags: iphone, nsdate

So basically, i've been trying a lot of the stuff i've read on here and elsewhere, and haven't been able to get this working.

I've been saving an NSDate as an object in UserDefaults with setObject etc. Then get current time with [NSData date] etc, my problem is comparison. I've seen other peoples examples and nothing seems to do what I need.

It's just an if statement and I need it to know to ++ the variable if 18 hours have passed from the last time they did it (and it saved the NSDate). Else it just displays a msg. The problem i'm having is I cant figure out how to check if current date > saved date by 18hours +. Could someone please help? I've tried turning them into NSTimeIntervals and calculating from that but somehow I screw this up.

Comment: I'm hoping you have a good reason for this (and will assume so until told otherwise) but I'd be _damn_ annoyed if an application tried to dictate to me that I could only use it once a day. For a start, what if it crashed (after writing the date but before I could do anything useful) or I exited by accident? Not saying your approach is wrong, just that I hope you've given it enough thought.

Comment: Oh, the app has a lot of features (15~ total) and this is more of a rewards feature that I dont want incremented more than once daily is all. Just a bonus feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'd store a *LastAccessDate* in `NSUserDefaults` for that app. Upon app open, launch, active, etc I'd check to see that this value was less than 18 hours with `timeIntervalSinceNow`. Check out the [NSDate Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Example (not tested):

```
NSDate *lastAccessDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LastAccessDate"]]
NSTimeInterval duration = [lastAccessDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
int hoursPassed = duration / 3600;
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by limit use to once a day? You mean only let the app do something useful once a day? Surely this is a road to App Store rejection, especially if you don't let the user do anything at all once the app is loaded.

In any event, if you want to proceed with such things, the logic is probably something like this:

```
NSDate *lastSyncDate = (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"last_app_rundate"];  
NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:lastSyncDate];

if ((interval / 3600) >= 18) {
   // let your user use your app
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"last_app_rundate"];
}
```

edit: too slow to answer!

Comment: Yea this is just a rewards part of the app and I dont want them racking up points, just once a day. The rest of the app will remain fully functioning. Thanks to all for the fast responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSTimeInterval dateDiff = [lastAccessDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
int hours=trunc(dateDiff/(60*60));
```